# My Visual Studio run the angular project after change not refreshing my browser?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I have already added an angular project and I was run the project using ng serve / npm start it's ok. question is I open a project and do some changes after ctrl+s / file/all save but project server not recompiling. browser not refreshing. please help me. my os is mint Linux . project is genarate using ng new.

Comment: Which file did you change ?

Comment: I changed on component.html

Comment: did you try to reload vscode ?

Comment: yeah. I did.  and re-installed  the vs code

Comment: I fixed the issue. I reinstall the node js. after compiling is woking and also browser refreshed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I reinstall the node js. after compiling is woking and also browser refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

make sure the "auto save" is enable in your visualStudioCode.
**File>auto save**

Comment: read the question. it says they saved.